# Proxy to work with OpenLayers and Geoserver Locally with IIS express

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, proxy, iis

I need to set a proxy to work with OpenLayers and Geoserver, which are both using a different port on my pc. I'm the site with openlayers is hosted **IIS express** and I'm not using Apache (so the proxy.cgi solution is not for me). I need it to perform a wmsgetfeatureinfo and, at this point, I really don't know what to put in `OpenLayers.ProxyHost =`. Can you help?

Comment: if your IIS server can run python cgi, then you can use the proxy.cgi solution. It is not specific to apache.

Comment: I'm trying to use both the proxy.cgi and proxy.php but, when I use them, I get the error 404.3. How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have access to Visual Studio?

Comment: No, I'm using WebMatrix 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: simply, if you are using the WebMatrix like me, you can install the PHP from the settings of the program directly into the iis. This way, I'm able to use the proxy made in php and it works perfectly!